# SQL Database Project in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I have a database ready which I am maintaining manually, I would like to now use that database to create an SQL project. I am creating also but not able to import the existing Tables, Views, Stored Procedures or any other object. Is there any way to do it. If yes please let me know.

Thanks,
Piyush

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any reverse-engineering support for databases in Visual Studio.

What you need to do is script out your existing SQL database into *.sql files from SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

and then import those as "Create Scripts" into your database project in Visual Studio. Any further changes can be added as "Change Scripts" to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Database Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/australia/visualstudio/products/teamsystem/default.mspx) of Visual Studio (not to be confused with the older 'Database Project') you can generate a complete set of scripts that can be added to source control. Data and schema comparison tools are also included.

This tool was originally known as 'Data Dude' and is available for Visual Studio 2005 and higher.